# Identify curve in binary image

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a few screenshots from experiments which display curves, and I want to extract that curve into an array to analyze the data.

The first part of my method is to transform the image into a binary one with a well chosen threshold that only leaves the curve. This works fine, but the second part consisting in extracting an array from the curve doesn't.  I tried the "naive" method of going through the picture and identifying the white pixels, but the results are nowhere near what's expected.

Does someone have a solution?

[image: A screenshot example]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.Image as img

gray = img.open('0100k.jpg').convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<240 else 255, '1')
bw = bw.convert('1')
bw.show()
pix = np.array(bw)
(n,m) = pix.shape
curve = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if pix[i,j] == 1:
        curve[i] = j
plt.plot(curve)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder if you have your `i` and `j` reversed because `np.array` returns a list of lists. The first element accesses the inner lists (vertical) and the second element accesses the individual elements of each list (horizontal).

Comment: You're right. Also, the 0,0 point is in the upper left corner, so to make it work I just found it is better like this :
`(n,m) = pix.shape  
curve = np.zeros(m)  
for i in range(n):  
    for j in range(m):  
       if pix[i,j] == 1:  
            curve[j] = n-i`

Comment: Ah, well,l I'm glad you have it figured out. It's a source of frustration for me, too. In all of mathematics, the origin is in the bottom-left-hand corner. Why many libraries insist otherwise is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the method now works, the solution was in the correct assignation of i and j to their respective dimensions. Thanks to @Matt Cremens for pointing it out.
But the plot thickens, it detects some non-existing pixels, like the ones visibles in the left side of the picture : http://s31.postimg.org/i0conbbxn/figure_1.png